# How to ask many related questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been looking into $n$-bit Gray codes just a bit recently, and I have several questions about them, especially since they have so many different interpretations: Hamiltonian paths in $n$-unit hypercubes, or equivalently permutations of the group $(\mathcal{P}([n]),\oplus)=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{n}$ (where $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$, and $\oplus$ is the symmetric difference) where consecutive elements differ by an element of a fixed generating set, using automorphisms to generalize the Gray code to multi-bit changes, certain interesting recursive constructions of Gray codes, a combinatorial question, etc.

I know the rules emphasize a one question per post policy. How should I deal with trying to ask questions like these, where I am interested in exploring a collection of different interpretations/relationships, all related to a single concept, but which do not really stem from a single question? Should I just ask different questions and refer to previous ones? Or would it be accepted as a single question? Maybe modify the question into something big-list-like?

Comment: They're probably better asked individually, but I'd ask one and see how the answers to that change your need to ask more questions.  Asking six questions in quick succession may result in overlap of answers and possibly less attention when people see you've asked all the top questions on the home page :)

Comment: The key word you used is "explore". Unfortunately, this web site is pretty strongly _not_ for "exploring" or "discussing", but for answering questions. So you should do the exploring either on your own or with some other site/group, and when you hit a question, post it here. BTW, discussing your motivation and what angle you're coming at the question from can be helpful to include when you post here -- it helps people know how to answer -- but it's just for background, and you'll get pushback if you try to turn your specific question into a general discussion.